# RMarkdown stops rendering at 80% quietly when knitting to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr

I have a very long RMarkdown script that I am trying to render to PDF.

Have been working on this script for quite a while (2 months +). On and off during my project I would render it to PDF just to make sure it works, and it did, but recently after adding in my last parts (more chunks and text) it knits until 83% and suddenly just stops.

The code runs fine on R. I have seen online that it could be an “out-of-memory” issue so on some of the later chunks I make sure to remove data frames that I no longer use, but the RMD still stops knitting at the same chunk which is about 80%, via the rm() function.

Have tried restarting R, clearing the environment, and monitor task manager to see if memory reaches the maximum, but they don’t seem to work (task manager doesn’t indicate that memory is too high)

Could it be the plots that I am saving? Or does anyone else have a solution?

My YAML is

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

Comment: The reason for a delay could be many things, ranging from long-process, `tinytex` updates, R package update/installation, network hang, I/O issues, etc. I'm not sure we can provide much assistance without knowing what the code blocks are, but at least you know where to start: the code chunks you recently added. Disable one at a time until the rendering completes.

Comment: @r2evans thank you so much! it turns out that the chunk was suddenly problematic and was causing R to crash, even though it was fine before, and because of that it wasn't showing an errors on the Render panel.